# How to make SQL query run faster within VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, performance

**Problem**

I want to improve the speed of a VBA macro which was created many years ago by retired colleague.

I have basically rewritten the entire VBA side of things to bring it up to modern standards and that bit is now fine.

But there is a SQL query within the original code that runs so slowly, at the minute it is taking around 25 minutes for the query to complete.

I have literally zero knowledge of SQL, so I don't know if it is written with best practices in mind etc.

(FYI the purpose of the code/macro is to access the manufacturing server and see how much product was run through a machine within the specified date)

The VBA code:

```
Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DATABASE=imps_restricted;DESCRIPTION=Read Only access to Imps Database;DSN=ReadOnlyLinc18imps;OPTION=0;PWD=reporter;PORT=0;SERVER=linc18;U" _
    ), Array("ID=reporter")), Destination:=Range("A1"))
With QT
    .Sql = Array( _
    "SELECT travellerdetail_0.BatchName, travellerdetail_0.BatchVersion, travellerdetail_0.RecipeName, travellerdetail_0.QtyIn, travellerdetail_0.DateIn, travellerdetail_0." _
    , _
    "DateOut, recipe_0.Description" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM imps.recipe recipe_0, imps.travellerdetail travellerdetail_0" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE recipe_0.RecipeName = travellerdetail_0.RecipeName AND recipe_0.RecipeVersion = travellerdetail_" _
    , _
    "0.RecipeVersion AND ((travellerdetail_0.EquipmentName='" _
    , _
    SearchId & "') AND ((travellerdetail_0.DateIn>{ts '" & StartDate & " " & StartTime _
    , _
    "'}) AND (travellerdetail_0.DateIn<{ts '" & EndDate & " " & EndTime & "'}) OR (travellerdetail_0.DateOut>{ts '" & StartDate & " " & StartTime _
    , _
    "'}) AND (travellerdetail_0.DateOut<{ts '" & EndDate & " " & EndTime & "'})))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY travellerd" _
    , "etail_0.DateIn")
    .FieldNames = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
End With

QT.Delete
```

Obviously there is a lot more to the macro then this but this is just the SQL part, as I said the VBA part is fine.

Can anyone help me with possible suggestions on how to maybe make this query run faster?

PS: I am thinking that maybe it can not really be sped up due to the shear amount of data it will be looking at. As I am presuming that the query would look at all of the data ever before it filters based on the date? I don't know though...

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  travellerdetail_0.BatchName, 
        travellerdetail_0.BatchVersion, 
        travellerdetail_0.RecipeName, 
        travellerdetail_0.QtyIn, 
        travellerdetail_0.DateIn, 
        travellerdetail_0.DateOut, 
        recipe_0.Description
FROM    imps.recipe recipe_0, imps.travellerdetail travellerdetail_0
WHERE   recipe_0.RecipeName = travellerdetail_0.RecipeName AND 
        recipe_0.RecipeVersion = travellerdetail_0.RecipeVersion AND 
        (
         (travellerdetail_0.EquipmentName=' ') AND 
          (
           (travellerdetail_0.DateIn>{ts '   '}) AND 
           (travellerdetail_0.DateIn<{ts ' '}) OR 
           (travellerdetail_0.DateOut>{ts '     '}) AND 
           (travellerdetail_0.DateOut<{ts ' '})
          )
        )
ORDER BY travellerdetail_0.DateIn
```

**The plot thickens, after analysing the code a bit more the part where it starts to slow down is the `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` part. I am guessing this is where the PC starts talking to the server?? how do I get this part to speed up?**

Comment: Add index to `DateIn` and `DateOut` fields in your database `travellerdetail_0` table

Comment: Ask one of your company's DBAs to profile the execution of the query. That will tell them exactly where the server is spending the most time on execution. They may even be able to just look at the query and tell you where it's not accessing indices on either of the tables and what to add.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful for us (and your DBA) if you posted the actual SQL query, instead of the string concatenation that builds it

Comment: We don't have a database admin lol that I am aware off lol... I am just a Physicist trying to dabble in some coding ot see what what's been run on what machine etc... I am also not sure what you by the actual SQL query? The code that I posted is basically all that runs apart from soem VBA bull around it... Unless you mean that the code I posted goes to the server or whatever and then some SQL runs? if thats the case I don't know how to access the SQL aha